# After saving the queen, Marle doesn't reappear

Tags: chrono-trigger

I'm playing the Steam release of Chrono Trigger, and after saving Queen Leene in 600 AD, Marle isn't reappearing as expected in the Queen's chambers.

I'm expecting this to happen based on this guide: https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Chrono_Trigger/The_Queen_is_Gone

I've never actually played this game before. The Queen is on her throne, Frog has swam across the broken bridge. In the Queen's chambers is an attendant that says something about the fake chancellor being preferable over the real one.

**Why is Marle not reappearing?**

**Edit**

- I have rescued the chancellor.
- I have talked to the Queen, who reminded Lucca about Marle.
- Between talking to the Queen and going to the Queen's chambers, I ate a meal in the kitchen and slept in the barracks. I also left the castle, went the the bridge and talked to the guard there about Frog swimming across.

This is a blocker for me ...

Comment: Have you rescued the chancellor from the other chest?

Answer (score 4):

Two things you may have forgotten to do:

1. **Rescue the Chancellor:** <strike>he is in the chest on the left hand side of the room in the Boss Fight with Yakra. If you do not rescue him, the cutscene does not play out properly.</strike> If you accidentally leave the Chancellor in the chest, he will rescue himself when you leave the room. (That said, you have mentioned that Frog has left, so this might not be the case).
2. **Talk to Queen Leene:** after the cutscene with Frog, you actually need to talk to Leene, and she will ask "what happened to the girl that was mistaken for me?" Lucca will then react, and ask you to go check out the room where she disappeared from, which should trigger the cutscene where she reappears.

Outside of this, there should be no reason for her not to appear, so it may be a bug in the save file.

---

As per the comments: the OP found they were going to the wrong room, which is why Marle wasn't appearing.

After talking to the Queen, and Lucca "remembering" about Marle, you will need to enter the doorway to the *right* at the back of the Throne Room, which will lead to the Queen's Chambers, where you will find Marle (the door to the left leads to the King's Chambers).

Comment: I have talked to the Queen. She says "whatever happened to that girl" or somesuch, and Lucca said "We should go to where she disappeared". Now, between that and going to the Queen's room (I went the wrong way), I did eat a meal in the kitchen and sleep in the barracks. I just went back and talked to the Queen, then back to the room ... nada. At least it's early if I have to restart.

Comment: From what I can see from extra digging, this does look like a bug, sadly :(

Comment: Did you find anything related to this, or just nothing other than what we already know?

Comment: Nothing that we don't already know. I wasn't able to find anything regarding this particular situation other than what I've already provided.